# How do I ensure a trailing forward slash is present in the URI for a REST resource that's a collection?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

We have a REST convention/guideline in our company to use a trailing slash on a URI for a REST resource, if that resource is a collection.

- `GET /<resources>/` to list resources
- `GET /<resources>/<resourceId>` to get a specific resource
- `POST /<resources>/` to create a resource
- `PUT /<resources>/<resourceId>` to replace a resource
- `PATCH /<resources>/<resourceId>` to update a resource
- `DELETE /<resources>/<resourceId>` to delete a resource

Note the trailing `/` to list resources and to create a resource.

The purpose of this guideline is to convey to the API consumer that the resource is a collection. I'm trying to achieve this by including the trailing slash in the Open API specification. It's important to note that the API need not be strict about the trailing slash when responding to actual requests - it's more a documentation thing.

I have a .NET 7 Web API project that uses Swashbuckle.AspNetCore to generate the Open API spec, and I'm struggling to find a clean way of achieving this.

Using attribute routing, the trailing slash is ignored. This is what the `Route` attribute on the controller looks like:

`[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/schools/")]`

However, in the Open API spec, the path is missing the trailing slash:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: LMS.API
  version: '1.0'
paths:
  /api/v1/schools:
    post:
      tags:
        - Schools
```

Is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think this is easily feasible with any tool that was built for / adheres to / enforces REST API conventions.

The reason is that the trailing slash convention/guideline you settled on goes against common REST design principles.

That is not just my opinion, but can be looked up in the [REST API Design Rulebook, by Mark Massé](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/rest-api-design/9781449317904/), page 12:

> « **A trailing slash (/) should not be included in URIs**: As the last character within a URI’s path, a forward slash (/) adds no semantic value and may cause confusion. REST APIs should not expect a trailing slash and should not include them in the links that they provide to clients.»

Comment: I suppose the semantic value it adds is to convey to the API consumer the fact that the endpoint represents a collection, which has further, more specific endpoints (i.e. for retrieving and updating specific resources within that collection).

Comment: I understand your company's motivation, but it does not change that the trailing slash notation is against common REST conventions. In a way, that blocks you from using tooling that adheres to the conventions. If your goal is to communicate additional semantics to an API user or client, it would make more sense to go with a standardized documentation or API discovery solutions for just that, e.g. [OpenAPI](https://www.openapis.org) (documentation) or [HATEOAS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hateoas-and-why-its-needed-in-restful-api/) (dynamic resource discovery)